# Utilizing UART/Serial port driver inside another Linux module/driver

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, kernel-modules, uart

I am implementing a network module/driver in Linux which uses `net_devices` structure. And so far I have been able to add and remove my module to and from kernel space using `insmod` command. Via `ifconfig` I set an ip to my newly created interface and was able to send ping packets. What I now need to do is  to capture `sk_buff` packets inside my `ndo_start_xmit` function and send/receive them through UART physical connectors. i.e. just as in the case of userspace applications where we would open a tty device through file descriptors (`/dev/tty*`) and write to for transmission (and read from for receiving), I now have to somehow detect or find my device in kernel space (inside my network module) and send or receive data through Rx and Tx lines. Below is my driver:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/etherdevice.h>

struct net_device *mynet;

int mynet_open(struct net_device *dev) {
   printk(KERN_ALERT "open called\n");
   return 0;
}

int mynet_release(struct net_device *dev) {
   printk(KERN_ALERT "release called\n");
   netif_stop_queue(dev);
   return 0;
}

int mynet_xmit(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev) {
   printk(KERN_ALERT "dummy xmit function called...\n");

   ///////// UART SEND HERE /////////

   dev_kfree_skb(skb);
   return 0;
}

int mynet_init(struct net_device *dev) {
   printk(KERN_ALERT "gohmnet0 device initialized\n");
   return 0;
}

const struct net_device_ops my_netdev_ops = {
    .ndo_init = mynet_init,
    .ndo_open = mynet_open,
    .ndo_stop = mynet_release,
    .ndo_start_xmit = mynet_xmit,
};

static void virtual_setup(struct net_device *dev){
   dev->netdev_ops = &my_netdev_ops;
}


int mynet_init_module(void) {
   int result;
   mynet = alloc_netdev(0, "mynet",NET_NAME_UNKNOWN, virtual_setup);
   if((result = register_netdev(mynet)))
   {
       printk(KERN_ALERT "mynet: Error %d initalizing card ...", result);
       return result;
   }
   return 0;
}

void mynet_cleanup (void)
{
   printk (KERN_ALERT "<0> Cleaning Up the Module\n");
   unregister_netdev (mynet);
}

module_init(mynet_init_module);
module_exit(mynet_cleanup);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

P.S. I have researched the following method and I need an alternative to it, so it is out of the question:

```
oldfs = get_fs();
set_fs(get_ds());
filp = filp_open(path, flags, rights);
set_fs(oldfs);
```

As a final note, it appears to me that I need to use UART driver in the kernel space in my own module/drive without jumping back and forth to user space.

Comment: Take a look at how the serial network drivers do it - e.g. drivers/net/slip/slip.c ... when the slip module is loaded it registers  a tty _line discipline_ so it doesn't need to do any mucking around with the UART ... a user level program must open a serial port and configure it with the slip line discipline, after that slip can operate a network interface over it.

Comment: @MurrayJensen Thanks for the reply. Just to be clear, are there any shortcut ways/exported functions in kernel space to which we could (potentially) send the required data to; this could be the process responsible for creating "/dev/ttyUSB0" in userspace persay; and hope for them to be delivered to the right hardware (e.g. TTL-232R usb from pc to raspberrypi rx and tx inputs) ? Or indeed we have to subclass from tty_struct, uart_driver etc and map the memory I/O addresses to the right USB/FTDI hardware as implemented in slip.c? (though I was not able to find those "mapping" codes in slip)

Comment: My point was that doing it the same way as the slip driver means you don't have to deal with any serial hardware - the tty driver does all that for you. That is why you can't find it in slip.c - it isn't there, it is in the tty driver. slip.c only has a simple line discipline driver.

Comment: I investigated slip.c (im a noob in kernel, persay) and realized, to the best of my knowledge, after the module is loaded into kernel space, I would have to externally attach my tty driver (which is inside my "combined" net and tty module) to a /dev/ttyS* device, once the physical USB is connected. It would then invoke my open() in my tty driver and hardware connection would establish. Is this accurate? (as you mentioned in the previous comment that slip.c does not address the hardware itself, but afterall, at some point I have to point my interface/driver to a specific USB connection right?)

Comment: yes, for the slip driver there is a user level program, usually called '"slattach", to do this. It will open a /dev/tty* file and set it to use the "tty" part of your module (it is called a "line discipline" and will be registered when your module is loaded).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It seems like slip mechanism is what exactly I was looking for (for now)